# Playing Multiple Videos when a user scrolls

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am using the following script to play a video when it scrolls into the viewport, and when the user scrolls off the video it stops. The problem is it will only play one video, if i add the same html for a different source video, a blank screen appears. Any help will be appreciated. Here is the code i have;

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/dist/skrollr.min.js"></script>
    <style type='text/css'></style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
    var s = skrollr.init({
        render: function(data) {
            var $seventh = $("#seventh");

            var $video = $("#video");
            var videoElem = $video[0];

            var videoTop = $video.offset().top;
            var videoBottom = videoTop + $video.height();

            var viewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            var viewBottom = viewTop + $(window).height();

            //play video when opacity is at least 50% and at least some of the video player is show
            var isViewable = $seventh.css("opacity") > 0.5 && (videoTop < viewBottom && videoBottom > viewTop);
            if(isViewable) {
                if(videoElem.paused) {
                    videoElem.play();
                    console.log("play");
                }
            }
            else {
                if(!videoElem.paused) {
                    videoElem.pause();
                    console.log("pause");
                }
            }
        }
    });
    s.setScrollTop(500);
});//]]>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're using an ID to find your video. Duplicate IDs won't work.

Comment: How would i change this to add multiple IDs? I am relatively new to JavaScript? Any help would be appreiciated

Comment: Classes. Learn about 'em.

Comment: ive tried doing the multiple ID  var $video = $("#video, #video1, #video3"); but it doesn't work, this is why i asked, but i shall go read up on classes, thank you for the help